# Создание приложения шифрования текста на JAVA \u0074

Tags: java, текст

Всем привет кто может подсказать код для создания вот такого текста \u0074\u0065\u0073\u0074
Пример кода должен выглядеть так

```
    public static String test(String data) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        md.update(data.getBytes());
        return bytesToHex(md.digest());
    }
    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        for (byte byt : bytes) result.append(Integer.toString((byt & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        return result.toString();                                              
    }                                                                          
}
```

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
final String str = "test";
String unicode = "";
for (int ch : str.toCharArray()) {
    unicode += "\\u" + Integer.toHexString(ch | 0x10000).substring(1);
}
System.out.println(unicode); // \u0074\u0065\u0073\u0074
```

Если делаете в классе, можно воспользоваться таким способом:

```
final class Unicode {

    public static String unicode = "";

    public static String encode(final String str) {
        str.chars().forEach(ch -> {
            Unicode.unicode += "\\u" + Integer.toHexString(ch | 0x10000).substring(1);
        });
        return Unicode.unicode;
    }
}
```